# QGIS3 - Maintain resolution of input rasters using raster calculator

Tags: raster, qgis-3, raster-calculator, resolution

In QGIS 3.28.4 after subtracting one raster layer from another using raster calculator, I notice that pixels in the results layer sometimes do not equal the difference between the input layers when randomly checking using the identify tool.

Both input rasters have the same CRS.
I put this down to the input layer resolutions (9.999999999999982236,-9.999999999999982236) being slightly different to the results layer (10,-10).

Is there a way of maintaining the resolution when subtracting rasters or is the resolution always rounded?

Comment: Could you add  also the xmin/xmax ymin/ymax extents of the image, and the image size in pixels. Does the difference make some real issues? The 14th decimal stand for quite a small distance at pico-femto meter class, so less than a radius of typical atoms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius. The difference may come from the floating point accuracy https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html. Value 9.999999999999982236 is stored as 10 if it is converted into floating point number.

Comment: Yes I know this difference is very small, but have no explanation for why there is a difference otherwise.  Further information below. Interestingly when I create an on the fly result layer there is no difference in values and the resolution is exactly the same.                                                                                          
Extent 747048.5972990358714014,9633198.7020199280232191 : 800178.5972990357549861,9678238.7020199280232191
Width 5313
Height 4504
Data type Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point

Comment: I believe that somewhere in the process either the extent or the resolution is converted from decimal numbers into floating point values, and then back from floating points into decimals. The conversion is not reversible for all decimal values.